# Font size is not changing onLoad of the email entity

Tags: javascript, email, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I am using the following script on email entity for changing the font size and font family of the description onLoad of the form.

```
function abc()
{
 var html = '<FONT size=3.5px face="Arial"></FONT>';

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("description").setValue(html.toString());

}
```

It changes the family accordingly and size as well. But the problem is the it set the size 11 (verify from MS word ) when I set the size from 3.5 to 3.9 and 13.5(verify from MS word )  when I set the size to 4.

Now I want to seek your kind suggestion and help in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the pixels from the size, as:

```
var html = '<FONT size=11 face="Arial"></FONT>';
```